# Regex to replace domain of url if it's ending with .css

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a php script to replace ONLY domain of every URL in the content with new domain if the URL ends with `.css`.

For example:

```
www.example.com/asset/css/style.css
```

After checking condition and replacement we have:

```
www.new-domain.net/asset/css/style.css
```

Would anyone please help me to find the correct pattern for this.

So far I've tried this:

```
preg_replace('/[http://].*\.(css)/i','www.new-domain.net',$Html_contents)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood, you should try something like:

```
preg_replace('/(https?:\/\/|)?[^\/]*(?=\/.*\.css$)/i','$1www.new-domain.net',$Html_contents)
```

Where

- `(https?:\/\/|)` means that the string `http://` (or `https://`) is optional
- `[^\/]*` means "anithing but `/`"
- `(?=\/.*\.css$)` means "a `/`, followed by anything, followed by a literal dot, followed by `css`, followed by end of string"

[See demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Qnzfee/1).

Answer (score 0):

if the domain is static you can try this without using regex

```
$old_domain = 'https://www.example.com/asset/css/style.css';
if (substr($old_domain, -4) == '.css'){
echo str_replace('www.example.com', 'www.new-domain.net', $old_domain);
}
```

Comment: no URL is not static, and the content is not just one or two url, content is a huge html file stored in a variable !  it contains so many URLs which needs to be modified if the resource of Url is a css file , therefore , i can't use your method .